# Pest control company terminated my contract then charged me termination fees

Tags: contract-law, texas

Had a pest control company who I’ve always had issues with them showing up at odd hours unannounced to perform services which were not scheduled. I am a new father and very protective and I finally got frustrated and said some unsavory things to them and they terminated my contract then charged me a $200 early termination fee. My question is, shouldn’t the party that broke the contract be responsible for the termination fees?? Surely they can’t force their customers to pay termination fees if the customers never broke contract.

Comment: The "unsavory things" you said to them could possibly be reasonably understood as _your_ termination of the contract, don't you think?

Comment: I was complaining about how they need to schedule visits. Never said anything about wanting to cancel service.

Comment: @Greendrake Not really, that's not how contract law works. Unless there is a clause which says "Party A may terminate the contract by saying unsavory things to party B". I've never seen such a clause. It's much more usual to have a clause such as "Party B shall be able to terminate the contract if Party A [does some particular act]", in which case it would be Party B doing the termination. In any case I've voted to close because this is asking for legal advice but also it's impossible to answer without seeing the contract.

Comment: @JBentley Well, if the OP said to them for example "Go fuck yourself", that would be reasonably interpreted as "I don't want to see you here anymore" which is effectively termination of the contract.

Answer (score -1):

> shouldn’t the party that broke the contract be responsible for the termination fees?

Depends on what the contract says exactly.

Typically, termination fees are payable by the client if he/she terminates the contract. If the service provider does so, usually no one should pay any termination fees to anyone.

So, if I was in your place and was sure that I did not terminate the contract, I would just not pay the $200. If they charged my credit card, I would file a chargeback with the bank.

Comment: If the service provider cancels the contract due to something they deem the clients fault, it would normal to consider that a cancellation by the client. Anyway, the way forward is to call them and ask, ignoring someone who might have a valid claim is just going to end in even more legal trouble or debt collectors knocking.